# How can I capture and scp an image on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to capture an image with raspistill and then send it to an other machine using scp.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

d=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T"`
fn="img_$d.jpg"
raspistill -o "$fn"
sshpass -p "my-password" scp "$fn" username@tola:/volume1/public/webcam
```

And I'd like to have an image every 2 minutes. So I created a crontab

```
pi@octoprint:~/bin $ crontab -l
MAILTO=""
*/2 * * * * /home/pi/bin/take.sh >> /var/log/take.log 2>&1
```

If I execute the script by hand, everything works as excpected. The image is captured and sent to the other server.

But the cronjob does not seam to do anything. The log stays emtpy, even if I add -v switches to the commands.

```
pi@octoprint:/var/log $ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Jun 25 17:56:01 octoprint CRON[18788]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/bin/take.sh >> /var/log/take.log 2>&^M)
Jun 25 17:58:01 octoprint CRON[18834]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/bin/take.sh >> /var/log/take.log 2>&^M)
Jun 25 18:00:01 octoprint CRON[18878]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/bin/take.sh >> /var/log/take.log 2>&^M)

pi@octoprint:/var/log $ l take.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 25 17:06 take.log
```

Any ideas what's missing?

Comment: Use absolute paths also in your script.

Comment: I think the crontab is malformed. What did you edit it with? See the end of each line in syslog, that ^M looks suspicious. By the way, do you have permissions, as the `pi` user, to write to /var/log/take.log?

Comment: You where both right. Changed everything to absolute path, got rid of the ^M and loged to a folder with appropriate rights. Everything is working now. Feel free to add your comments as an answer so you get the credits.